# How to output calculations in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, import

I have a csv file created with 6 rows, 1 column (header and 5 numbers). I want to be able to do a conversion, say from centimeters to inches, and save it in a new csv with a new header.

So far I have only been able to import the csv and read it, and print it (using print row), but how can I do the conversion? Since the numbers are saved in the csv, would I have to convert the numbers to float and then write them to a new csv? I only have 5 numbers as I want to be able to just figure out the correct code, but I will use this for a lot of numbers.

I wasn't sure where the computation would be placed either. Help please! Also, this isn't homework or the like. Im just doing this for fun.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)   # I did this to skip the header I labelled Centimeters 

with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as o:
    writer = csv.writer(o)
    for row in reader


f.close()
o.close()
```

I guess I dont know how to convert the number in the rows to float and then output the values. I want to just be able to multiply the number in the row by 0.393701 so that in the new csv the header is labelled inches with the output beneath in the rows.

Comment: You don't need to have the `f.close()` and `o.close()`. The `with` statement automatically does that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, assuming a single column (for multiple columns the handling would differ some to output all the values, but the general concept would be the same):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f, open('test1.csv', 'wb') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(o)

    # skip the header
    next(reader, None)

    # print the new header
    writer.writerow(['inches'])

    for row in reader:
        newVal = float(row[0]) * 0.393701
        writer.writerow([newVal])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
float_rows=[]
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader, None)   # I did this to skip the header I labelled Centimeters
    for row in reader:  
        comp = [ x * 0.393701 for x in map(float,row)] # do calculations and map elements to float
        float_rows.append(comp)


with open('test1.csv', 'wb') as o:
    writer = csv.writer(o)
    writer.writerows(float_rows) # write all computed data to new csv
```

No `close` needed, `with` closes the files automatically.

Using `map(float,iterable)` is the same as `[float(x) for x in my_iterable]`